# IFRAME redirecting to source in mobile device

Tags: iframe, mobile, cross-browser, cross-domain, redirect

In my website eg (www.ABC.com), there is an iFRAME with a source (www.XYZ.com).

iFRAME source is rendered on a button click.

> **PC / Desktop**

Works as expected. Click on the button loads the iFRAME with the source.

> **Mobile (all browser / All Device)**

When button is clicked, www.ABC.com is redirected to iFRAME's Source i.e., www.XYZ.com.

What is the problem ?

Comment: Share the code on button click..

Comment: $("#button-play").on("mouseup touchend",function(){return browser.inIframe()&&browser.isMobile()?void(top.location.href=self.location.href):void

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the `void` is setting the iframe's source. If it is mobile, then it is also setting it's parents source to same.. which might be causing the problem..

```
$("#button-play").on("mouseup touchend",
    function(){
      return void;
    });
```

**EDIT :**

So, as per your situation..

Firstly, Give a id to your iframe.. `<iframe id='myFrame' ... >`

Now, to unbind all click events from the button (say, its `id='myBtn'`) ..

```
$('iframe#myFrame').contents().find('#myBtn').off( "click", "**" );
```

Or, to unbind all events from the button ..

```
$('iframe#myFrame').contents().find('#myBtn').off();
```

Now, assign your function to this button..

```
$('iframe#myFrame').contents().find('#myBtn').on( "click", function() {
        //your code to fire on click of myBtn
    });
```

Let me know if it works for you.. :)

Comment: DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "www.XXX.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Comment: Sorry,.. this is the error $('matterport').contents().find('#myBtn').off();
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contents' of null